# Draw Path From Lat/Long

Tags: android, sqlite

I want to draw path of my lat long position on a map from SQLite. Is it possible and can anyone help me with this on Android? I've attached my map activity for location.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow! Please read www.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask to see how to ask proper questions.

Comment: Priyanka what exactly you want to do i cant understand ..can you exaplain it.??

Comment: you just want to draw path between current Location to destination location??

Answer (score 2):

You can try this

```
PolylineOptions rectOptions = new PolylineOptions()
        .add(new LatLng(37.35, -122.0))
        .add(new LatLng(37.45, -122.0))  // North of the previous point, but at the same longitude
        .add(new LatLng(37.45, -122.2))  // Same latitude, and 30km to the west
        .add(new LatLng(37.35, -122.2))  // Same longitude, and 16km to the south
        .add(new LatLng(37.35, -122.0)); // Closes the polyline.

// Get back the mutable Polyline
Polyline polyline = myMap.addPolyline(rectOptions);
```

or for database

```
Cursor cursor = database,getData("your query");
PolylineOptions rectOptions = new PolylineOptions();

if(cursor!=null && cursor.getCount()>0 && cursor.moveToFirst())
{

do
{

String lt  = cursor.getString(curor.getColumnIndex("columnName"));
double lat = Double.parseDouble(lt);
String ln  = cursor.getString(curor.getColumnIndex("columnName"));
double lng = Double.parseDouble(ln);


        rectOptions.add(new LatLng(lat, lng)); // Closes the polyline.

// Get back the mutable Polyline



}while(cursor.moveToNext());

}
Polyline polyline = myMap.addPolyline(rectOptions);
```

Comment: Thank you sir,Above database code work for me now I want to join my location by route. Can you help me for joining my locations by route

Comment: yes you can you need to use the googe api to get teh route between two locations

Comment: Sir How it can be implement into code please help me

Comment: I just post another answer for draw route between two locations

Answer (score 0):

```
**Create Seperate class**

class DirectionsJSONParser {

    /**
     * Receives a JSONObject and returns a list of lists containing latitude and longitude
     */
    public List<List<HashMap<String, String>>> parse(JSONObject jObject) {

        List<List<HashMap<String, String>>> routes = new ArrayList<List<HashMap<String, String>>>();
        JSONArray jRoutes = null;
        JSONArray jLegs = null;
        JSONObject jDistance = null;
        JSONArray jSteps = null;

        try {

            jRoutes = jObject.getJSONArray("routes");

            /** Traversing all routes */
            for (int i = 0; i < jRoutes.length(); i++) {
                jLegs = ((JSONObject) jRoutes.get(i)).getJSONArray("legs");
                List path = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

                /** Traversing all legs */
                for (int j = 0; j < jLegs.length(); j++) {
                    /** Getting distance from the json data */
                    jDistance = ((JSONObject) jLegs.get(j)).getJSONObject("distance");
                    HashMap<String, String> hmDistance = new HashMap<String, String>();
                    hmDistance.put("distance", jDistance.getString("value"));
                    jSteps = ((JSONObject) jLegs.get(j)).getJSONArray("steps");

                    /** Adding distance object to the path */
                    path.add(hmDistance);

                    /** Traversing all steps */
                    for (int k = 0; k < jSteps.length(); k++) {
                        String polyline = "";
                        polyline = (String) ((JSONObject) ((JSONObject) jSteps.get(k)).get("polyline")).get("points");
                        List<LatLng> list = decodePoly(polyline);

                        /** Traversing all points */
                        for (int l = 0; l < list.size(); l++) {
                            HashMap<String, String> hm = new HashMap<String, String>();
                            hm.put("lat", Double.toString(((LatLng) list.get(l)).latitude));
                            hm.put("lng", Double.toString(((LatLng) list.get(l)).longitude));
                            path.add(hm);
                        }
                    }
                    routes.add(path);
                }
            }

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }

        return routes;
    }

    /**
     * Method to decode polyline points
     * Courtesy : http://jeffreysambells.com/2010/05/27/decoding-polylines-from-google-maps-direction-api-with-java
     */
    private List<LatLng> decodePoly(String encoded) {

        List<LatLng> poly = new ArrayList<LatLng>();
        int index = 0, len = encoded.length();
        int lat = 0, lng = 0;

        while (index < len) {
            int b, shift = 0, result = 0;
            do {
                b = encoded.charAt(index++) - 63;
                result |= (b & 0x1f) << shift;
                shift += 5;
            } while (b >= 0x20);
            int dlat = ((result & 1) != 0 ? ~(result >> 1) : (result >> 1));
            lat += dlat;

            shift = 0;
            result = 0;
            do {
                b = encoded.charAt(index++) - 63;
                result |= (b & 0x1f) << shift;
                shift += 5;
            } while (b >= 0x20);
            int dlng = ((result & 1) != 0 ? ~(result >> 1) : (result >> 1));
            lng += dlng;

            LatLng p = new LatLng((((double) lat / 1E5)),
                    (((double) lng / 1E5)));
            poly.add(p);
        }

        return poly;
    }
}

 - **In Activtiy**


 private String getDirectionsUrl(LatLng origin, LatLng dest) {

        // Origin of route
        String str_origin = "origin=" + origin.latitude + "," + origin.longitude;

        // Destination of route
        String str_dest = "destination=" + dest.latitude + "," + dest.longitude;

        // Sensor enabled
        String sensor = "sensor=false";

        // Building the parameters to the web service
        String parameters = str_origin + "&" + str_dest + "&" + sensor;

        // Output format
        String output = "json";

        // Building the url to the web service
        String url = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/" + output + "?" + parameters;

        return url;
    }

    // Fetches data from url passed
    private class DownloadTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

        // Downloading data in non-ui thread
        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... url1) {
            // For storing data from web service
            String data = "";
            try {
                // Fetching the data from web service
                InputStream iStream = null;
                HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;
                try {
                    URL url = new URL(url1[0]);

                    // Creating an http connection to communicate with url
                    urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                    // Connecting to url
                    urlConnection.connect();
                    // Reading data from url
                    iStream = urlConnection.getInputStream();
                    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(iStream));
                    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                    String line = "";
                    while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                        sb.append(line);
                    }
                    data = sb.toString();
                    br.close();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    Log.d(TAG, e.toString());
                } finally {
                    iStream.close();
                    urlConnection.disconnect();
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.d(TAG, e.toString());
            }
            return data;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);
            ParserTask parserTask = new ParserTask();
            // Invokes the thread for parsing the JSON data
            parserTask.execute(result);
        }
    }

    private class ParserTask extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, List<List<HashMap<String, String>>>> {

        // Parsing the data in non-ui thread
        @Override
        protected List<List<HashMap<String, String>>> doInBackground(String... jsonData) {

            JSONObject jObject;
            List<List<HashMap<String, String>>> routes = null;

            try {
                jObject = new JSONObject(jsonData[0]);
                DirectionsJSONParser parser = new DirectionsJSONParser();

                // Starts parsing data
                routes = parser.parse(jObject);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return routes;
        }

        // Executes in UI thread, after the parsing process
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(List<List<HashMap<String, String>>> result) {
            ArrayList<LatLng> points;
            PolylineOptions lineOptions = null;
            // Traversing through all the routes
            for (int i = 0; i < result.size(); i++) {
                points = new ArrayList<LatLng>();
                lineOptions = new PolylineOptions();

                // Fetching i-th route
                List<HashMap<String, String>> path = result.get(i);

                // Fetching all the points in i-th route
                for (int j = 0; j < path.size(); j++) {
                    HashMap<String, String> point = path.get(j);

                    if (j == 0) {    // Get distance from the list

                            String dist = point.get("distance");
                        if(dist!=null && dist.length()>0) {
                            int distInt = Integer.parseInt(dist);
                            sumDistance += distInt;
                        }
                        continue;
                    }
                    double lat = Double.parseDouble(point.get("lat"));
                    double lng = Double.parseDouble(point.get("lng"));
                    LatLng position = new LatLng(lat, lng);

                    points.add(position);
                }

                // Adding all the points in the route to LineOptions
                lineOptions.addAll(points);
                lineOptions.width(10);

                    lineOptions.color(Color.BLUE);

            }
            mGoogleMap.addPolyline(lineOptions);
            if (true) {
                // Drawing polyline in the Google Map for the i-th route
                mGoogleMap.addPolyline(lineOptions);
            }
            //Log.d(TAG, "map: " + map + "  lineoptions: " + lineOptions);
        }
    }

calling:

    String url = getDirectionsUrl(position, position1);
    DownloadTask downloadTask = new DownloadTask();
    // Start downloading json data from Google Directions API
    downloadTask.execute(url);
```

Comment: I cant understand above code adding latlng for position and position1........Below is my code plz tell me how it can be done

Comment: Hello sir, I use above code and it work in my case.I have another problem regarding to this is that, I want to disply only one route betwwen two points.....and here it shows multiple routes.Can u solve my problem